# Is there a hidden method to set the time in Materialize 1.0's timepicker?

Tags: materialize

According to [the docs](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html), I can programatically set the date for the `datepicker` like so:

```
    M.Datepicker.getInstance($('form').find(tmpVar)).setDate(new Date());
```

However, it doesn't list a similar method for the `timepicker` and `setTime()` doesn't work.

The method I had in place in the previous version of Materialize has broken in 1.0. Is this a case of it being left out of the docs, or is this something that is simply not possible with this new version?

Comment: Hey adam, I indeed made this test and it looks like there's a walkaround for this you might check it out. 
https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/6074

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful for another issue, but it doesn't seem to mention anything about timepicker